# How are Trove collections more efficient than the standard Java collections?

Tags: java, collections

In an interview recently, I was asked about how HashMap works in Java and I was able to explain it well and explain that in the worst case the HashMap may degenerate into a list due to chaining. I was asked to figure out a way to improve this performance but I was unable to do that during the interview. The interviewer asked me to look up "Trove".

I believe he was pointing to [this page](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/overview). I have read the description provided on that page but still can't figure out how it overcomes the limitations of the java.util.HashMap.

Even a hint would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: `The Trove maps/sets use open addressing instead of the chaining approach taken by the JDK hashtables.` What else do you want to hear?

Comment: Interviewers often have hobby horses.  They've read about something "cool" and they want to see how many others have heard of it.  I hardly think that not knowing about Trove disqualifies someone from being a competent Java developer; so this particular interview question was just a bit pointless.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - I didn't know about open addressing and didn't see any emphasis in the markup on that.

Comment: @DavidWallace - I agree with you. Luckily, they have proceeded with me to the next round. So, may be this question was really a check on whether I have heard about it.

Comment: Congratulations, @KumudSinha and good luck with the subsequent interviews.  Honestly, it seems to me that you answered this question intelligently and eloquently.  There is no way that not having heard of Trove should count against you in your candidacy for this position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key phrase there is *open addressing*. Instead of hashing to an array of buckets, all the entries are in one big array. When you add an element, if the space for it is already in use you just move down the array to find a free space.

As long as the array is kept sufficiently bigger than the number of entries and the hash function is well distributed it's possible to keep average lookup times small. And by having one array you can get better performance - it's more cache friendly.

However it still has worst-case linear behaviour if (say) every key hashes to the same value, so it doesn't avoid that issue.

Comment: -1 for being very misleading. You gloss over the myriad of different probe sequences and pick the one with the *worst* worst-case behavior, linear probing. Linear probing lookup does no such thing as keeping average lookup times low, quite the opposite: It degenerates into O(n) search not only in the same cases as separate chaining does (hash collisions modulo table size), but also in other cases (such as clustering, i.e. lots of *nearby* hashes).

Comment: There's nothing in this answer that implies that the probe sequence has to be linear probing.  The comment by @delnan is kind of misleading.  Sure, this answer doesn't examine different probe sequences; but you could write a whole book on probing strategies if you were motivated to do so.

Comment: @DavidWallace I read "When you add an element, if the space for it is already in use you just move down the array to find a free space." to imply linear probing.

Comment: Suspect @delnan is a Trove committer :)

Comment: @David Thank you. I've tightened up the phrasing slightly.

Comment: Delnan, "move down the array" doesn't say "move down the array, entry by entry, in a linear fashion".  Don't read in what isn't there.

Comment: @DavidWallace Perhaps my reading comprehension has a bad day, in retrospect I'm not so sure -- don't read *that* to mean I agree with you ;-). Or perhaps Alan Stokes could clarify?

Comment: @delnan Glossing over the details of probing was intentional. Thanks for removing the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out open addressing. I wish the authors of original page had italicized _open addressing_ just like you.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me from the Trove page that there are two main differences that improve performance.

The first is the use of open addressing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing).  This doesn't avoid the collision issue, but it does mean that there's no need to create "Entry" objects for every item that goes in the map.

The second important difference is being able to provide your own hash function, which differs from the one provided  by the class of the keys.  So you could provide a much faster hash function if it made sense to do so.

Answer (score 5):

One advantage of Trove is that it avoids object creation, especially for primitives.
For big hashtables in an embedded java device this can be advantageous due fewer memory consumption.

The other advantage, I saw is the use of custom hash codes / functions without the need to override hashcode(). For a specific data set, and an expert in writing hash functions this can be an advantage.

Comment: +1 If I ever use Trove, it's when I have a primitive collection/map. The difference in that case really is measurable, especially in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks Marko, I never used Trove, but since I do embedded Java development, this SO question made me read the Trove overview. Good to know if one day i would need it.